# What's the point of downvotes when rep changes are reversed by deleting?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked a weak question which got a deserved downvote. It made me realise that what I'd asked was pretty lazy and badly explained, so I just deleted the question and went back to the drawing board. Doing so helped me solve my problem, which was nice, but I digress.

I was surprised to see that when I deleted the question I got back the -2 rep penalty I'd incurred with the downvote. This in turn made me question what the point of downvoting was.

I had always presumed that it served a twofold purpose. Firstly, to give users of the site a guide as to the quality of questions and answers when they were searching. Second, to act as a deterrent to people repeatedly asking bad questions or offering bad advice.

I think we'd all agree the first purpose is a good thing. The second, however, is more controversial. The fact that you can regain rep lost via downvotes by deleting would suggest that the site is not currently interested in that aspect of the downvoting system.

In which case: why bother giving people negative rep for accruing (and giving) downvotes in the first place?

Comment: Deleted questions still count for e.g. question bans; it's not a Get Out of Jail Free.

Comment: Wagging finger: you managed to sneak in a very hidden and unnoticed second question there with that *(and giving)* bit at the end :) You're also casually asking what the point is of negative rep when you apply a downvote which is completely the other side of the spectrum with an entirely different reasoning behind it.

Comment: I think you answer your own question in your second sentence. You realised it wasn't good quality and went to rethink how you could improve it

Comment: I think you can consider that reputation increase as a reward for removing downvoted posts from the page :)

Comment: No need to penalize people for life.  Once they've received the smack for a bad post, they can start again with a clean record.  This time knowing a bit more about how to proceed.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The loss of rep *encourages people to delete (or fix) bad content*.  We *want* people to delete useless content if they can't fix it.  It keeps the site clean, resulting in a high signal to noise ratio.

As far as a deterrent for preventing people from continuing to post bad posts, the -2 rep wouldn't really effectively accomplish that even if it stayed after the post was deleted; it's just so much smaller than the rep earned from upvotes.  Additionally, so much of the power here is in people's emotional reaction to the vote.  People don't like getting downvotes.  It typically makes them feel bad, which provides an incentive to avoid the bad behavior in the future, even if the rep is returned.

There are also systems in place, such as the post ban, to deal with users that really don't care about repeatedly posting bad content, even if they delete it.

Comment: Well, SO doesn't really draw peoples attention to downvotes, the rep-change-notice is only shown if there is a positive change (though negative ones are listed).

Comment: @DaniSpringer i see it the opposite way. A downvoted question should get seen less, because it is low quality. When it is edited (hopefully to make it high quality) it will be bumped back into view, where it can be voted on again.

Comment: The op is the best person to do so, and they can of course easily get to their own questions.

Comment: There are also review queues that help with this for newer users, the first posts queue and triage/H&I

Comment: I agree with Servy. When I downvote, I am usually _saying_ "delete this". I _want_ the poster to get the rep back — by deleting.

Comment: @DaniSpringer The OP is the one responsible for editing the question into shape.  If someone else wants to edit a post, that's great, but the OP is the one *responsible* for improving it.  Note that there are lots of tools for people interested in spending time improving posts to find posts that can use improvement, even if they've been downvoted off the front page.

Comment: "Signal to noise ratio".

Comment: Your answer looks good if the context is just what given in the question. However in a wider context it makes less sense. If I wrote a bad question, that was downvoted but then it has an answer that is upvoted, they system won't actually let me delete my bad question. So while in certain scenarios I can delete useless content as you described, in others system is actively preventing me doing so.

Comment: @zespri You are correct that my answer addresses the concerns of the question, and doesn't address other issues involving completely different situations.  If you're curious about those situations (after doing a bit of research to see if you can find an existing question about such circumstances) you can feel free to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 23):

Well, the rep changes are *very* low on the order of importance, especially considering how miniscule they are (they are more psychological than real).

Votes are, first and last, for indicating whether a post is useful for all the other viewers.

That signal is leveraged for:

1. Deleting posts.
2. Graying out bad answers / throwing bad questions off the front-page.
3. Throttling and banning bad posters.
4. Awarding moderation-privileges to those the community seems to trust enough, via reputation.

And if a user sees he can gain at least partial forgiveness by doing the right thing and either salvaging his post or deleting it himself, that reduces the strain on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's kind of what I'd assumed, but in that case, why bother with them at all?

Comment: Note that all of the points you've mentioned here (while true) don't have to do with the rep change of downvotes, and the decision to roll them back when the post is deleted.  All of these points would be equally valid if downvotes didn't remove 2 rep, or if that rep loss stayed after the post was deleted.

Comment: The question was, to quote it, "why bother giving people negative rep for accruing (and giving) downvotes in the first place?"  Given that all of these reasons would apply *even if downvotes didn't remove 2 rep*, it doesn't really answer it.

Comment: Except - if I can 'fix' my rep loss by deleting, I'm more likely to delete. I therefore decide if my post is fixable/improvable/erroneously downvoted (thus meaning better quality overall) or remove something poor from view (thus meaning better quality overall).